# ErrorException in BelongsToMany.php (Illegal offset type)

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5

I'm trying to insert a **belongsTo** to my pivot table. I have a **comments** and **documents** table that has a One to many relationship and **comments** and **users** table that has a many to many relationship. The pivot table is **comment_user**.

I can insert the **belongsTo** relationship but I'm having a problem where I need to insert the comments `id` together with the users `id`(Current user). See my relationship below.

**Database Diagram**

[image: DB]

**Models**:

Comment

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $tables = 'comments';

    protected $fillable =
    [
        'comment',
        'document_id',
    ];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User', 'comment_user', 'comment_id', 'user_id');
    }

    public function documents()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Document');
    }
}
```

User:

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract
{
    use Authenticatable;

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'middle_name',
        'email',
        'username',
        'address',
        'password',
        'role_permission_id',
    ];

 public function comments()
 {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Comment', 'comment_user', 'user_id', 'comment_id');
 }

}
```

Controller:

```
class CommentController extends Controller
{

    public function postComments(Request $request, Document $id)
    {

        $this->validate($request,
        [
            'comment' => 'required',
        ]);


        $commentObject = new Comment();


        $user = Auth::user();

        $commentObject->comment = $request->comment;

        $id->comments()->save($commentObject);

        $commentObject->users()->sync(['comment_id' => $commentObject, 'user_id' => $user->id],false);

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

**Problem**

I just wanted to insert the `id` of Model Comment and also the current user. I tried this but it says.

```
$commentObject->users()->sync(['user_id' => $user->id],false);
```

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`webdev`.`comment_user`, CONSTRAINT `comment_user_sender_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`sender_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `comment_user` (`comment_id`, `user_id`) values (36, 11))

As you can see here the **36** is the current id of Comment and the **11** is the current id of logged in user. Any help how can I achieve this?

Comment: Off-Topic: A user comment is in most cases a 1:n relation. So you can insert the user_id directly in the comment table and don't need a separate join table.

Comment: And pls add your tables structure `create table ...` to your question so we can check the constraints.

Comment: What said u-nik is very important and not that off topic. ```$user->comments()``` should be of type ```hasMany()```. A user **has Many** comments, and a comment **belongs To** a user. You should do it this way, it'll all become simpler.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this, you're trying to put null into sender_id which has a foreign key constraint. I assume you should also add a sender id like this:

```
$commentObject->users()->sync(['user_id' => $user->id, 'sender_id' => $whatever],false);
```